# Installing SQL Server 2012 alongside existing SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to Installing SQL Server 2012 alongside existing SQL Server 2008 on Window Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1 machine 64 Bit? I did do some research which were kind of confusing so wanted to be sure.

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to give it a unique instance name (e.g. `SQL2012`).

A few things to keep in mind:

- The new new instance will be controlled under a unique Windows Service name (it will share the name of the instance you assign). For example, you will be able to have your SQL Server 2008 instance running but your SQL Server 2012 stopped. Additionally, both can run under separate credentials.
- If you need to expose it via TCP/IP then you will need to assign a unique port that your new instance uses on the machine (this is done under the SQL Server Configuration Manager) and expose it through firewalls appropriately.